# Using CASE statement to only show certain results in a column (also creating duplicates)

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Sorry if that doesn't make sense—I wasn't sure how to word it. Let me try to explain better.

I'm currently working with a pretty basic query for looking at demographic information for patients who belong to a clinic. The query uses `CASE` statements to create a couple of new columns that are meant to be filterable in Excel for users reviewing the data later.

One of these `CASE` statements revolves around whether a patient is active with the clinic—they must be seen within the past 3 years to be considered active. The statement simply looks at the patient's last visit date, calculates the difference between that date and today's date, and then displays 'YES' if that difference is less than 3 years.

But then patients have what are known as flags. When a doctor accesses a patient's chart, different flags will pop up indicating that the patient is overdue for a service/treatment, has an unpaid bill, etc. One of the available flags is 'Inactive Patient!' which gets manually added by the medical records department when a chart gets deactivated, a patient dies or transfers care, and so on.

The aim with this query is to show all the demographic data for all the patients in the system, and then have a field with an indicator of whether they have the 'Inactive Patient!' flag, which can then be compared with whether or not they're active by the 3-year standard. So I have a second `CASE` statement set to display 'YES' if a patient has that flag attached to their chart. Mind you, I don't want to see *only* the inactive patients, but rather *all* available patients and whether or not those patients have the flag.

My query works, although once I added the new `CASE` statement to check for the inactive flag, it slowed way down and took a full 6 minutes to run. Granted, there are ~30,000 patients in the system, most of which have many flags attached to their chart, but that still seems like a long time. I'm also getting duplicate results for patients who do have the flag, since I'm selecting distinct records, but the first `CASE` statement for active-within-3-years patients doesn't create duplicates.

In short, I feel like I'm not going about this in the most efficient way possible. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to clean this up? See my query below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    d.PatientID
    ,d.PatientName
    ,...[other demographic fields like DOB, gender, race]
    ,a.LastVisitDate
    ,a.NextApptDate
    ,(CASE
        WHEN a.LastVisitDate > DATEADD(yy,-3,GETDATE()) THEN 'YES'
        ELSE ''
     END) AS [Active?]
    ,(CASE
        WHEN d.PatientFlag = 'Inactive Patient!' THEN 'YES'
        ELSE ''
     END) AS [Inactive Flag?]

FROM Demographic d FULL OUTER JOIN Appointment a ON d.PatientID = a.PatientID
```

Duplicate results end up looking like so. A patient with the inactive flag gets their entire row of demographic info repeated, and then one row shows the flag indicator while the other does not.

```
PatientID    PatientName    ...    LastVisitDate  NextApptDate  Active?    Inactive Flag?
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1001         John Smith     ...    01/03/2020     NULL          YES
1002         Jane Doe       ...    07/23/2020     12/29/2020    YES        
1002         Jane Doe       ...    07/23/2020     12/29/2020    YES        YES
1003         Bob Brown      ...    NULL           12/21/2020    YES
```

**Update:** here's an example of one of the actual duplicate results I'm getting. As we can see, one of this patient's rows has the inactive indicator created by the `CASE`, while the other does not (hence making them two unique rows). This patient was last seen this year so they are still active by the 3-year standard, but they no doubt have the inactive flag on their chart because they are now deceased. This patient also has a total of 35 past visits in the system, and clearly I'm not getting all 35 of those visits in my result. This is because the `LastVisitDate` and `NextApptDate` are unique and have a 1:1 relationship with `PatientID`.

[image]

Comment: Which table contains the duplicates?  I'm assuming the Appointment table?  It would make sense that an individual can have MANY appointments.  Next Question: Is the Demographic table a One-to-One to the PatientID or is it One-to-Many.  Basically in my opinion you need to take out the FULL OUTER JOIN... it really needs to be an INNER JOIN unless there's something about your data I'm not understanding.

Comment: Why `FULL JOIN`?

Comment: @CodeNovice I updated the question with an example of the duplicate results. The whole patient row is getting duplicated when someone has the inactive flag. Both the last visit date and next appt date fields are unique, each looking at just a single date.

Comment: @Eric I'm using the full join because not every patient has a valid last visit date or has a future appointment scheduled, so anyone with NULLs in those two fields was previously getting excluded.

Comment: So why not `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: If you simply SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM Demographic WHERE PatientID = 1002 how many records?  Same question for Appointment... It's hard to determine this since you are using a FULL OUTTER JOIN.  SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM Appointment WHERE PatientID = 1002.

Comment: Just because there are NULLs in these fields... that is not a good reason to use FULL OUTTER JOIN... again unless I'm not seeing something you are.

Comment: @Parfait I never said `CASE` itself added rows—the column contents created by the `CASE` appear to be what's adding rows, since it creates a new distinct record with that added field. `LastVisitDate` is simply the most recent date out of all of a patient's past visits, and `NextApptDate` is essentially the same thing in reverse. A patient may have multiple future visits scheduled, but this shows the first one.

Comment: @Parfait those fields are calculated by the system based on when the patient was last seen (what date they checked in for their most recent visit, I suppose) and when the next appointment is scheduled. They're generated automatically based on those things and not entered manually.

Comment: Those are case _expressions_, not statements. And tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @Parfait Yeah, unfortunately I didn't build this database and am merely a data analyst, not even a DBA. So I'm stuck with the structure I've been given. It's definitely a mess. We're switching to a new system in early 2021 so here's hoping the DB is built better.

Comment: I asked this on my answer, but I'll ask again here so others can see the answer. How many records does this return? Knowing this will help us with finding your solution:  `SELECT PatientID, COUNT(*) FROM Appointment GROUP BY PatientID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: Working on running that now...the system seems to be struggling today so it's taking a long time. In response to your previous question, a patient who is currently showing in my results with a duplicate row (like patient 1002 is in the example) has 35 total results if I pull all of their applicable data from the Appointment table. The query I'm working on only pulls 1 result since it's only looking at the most recent/next visit.

Comment: Update: `SELECT PatientID, COUNT(*) FROM Appointment GROUP BY PatientID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` returns 23,221 records

Comment: also @Eric you're right, left join works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need something like this...

You don't actually want ALL appointments, you just want the most recent appointment. Right?

```sql
SELECT d.PatientID, d.PatientName
    -- ...[other demographic fields like DOB, gender, race]
    , a.LastVisitDate
    , a.NextApptDate
    , IsActive     = CASE WHEN a.LastVisitDate > DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE()) THEN 'YES' ELSE '' END
    , InactiveFlag = CASE WHEN d.PatientFlag = 'Inactive Patient!' THEN 'YES' ELSE '' END
FROM Demographic d
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP(1) a.LastVisitDate, a.NextApptDate
        FROM Appointment a
        WHERE d.PatientID = a.PatientID
        ORDER BY a.LastVisitDate DESC
    ) a
```

Comment: The `LastVisitDate` field is already only showing the most recent appointment.

Comment: @EJF Does the Demographic table and the Appointment table have a 1 to 1 relationship on PatientID? Meaning, will `SELECT * FROM Demographic WHERE PatientID = 1` and `SELECT * FROM Appointment WHERE PatientID = 1`, will I always get 1 record?

Comment: the Demographic table, yes. The Appointment table contains all of a patient's past visits and upcoming appointments, but the `LastVisitDate` field shows the most recent visit in that table and `NextApptDate` shows the next one coming up, no matter how many are scheduled.

Comment: Right, so if you have 3 Appointment records for 1 Demographic record, you'll end up with Demographic duplicated 3 times. Have you tried running my query to see if it gets what you want? The problem is that you want to pick a single Appointment record, and you probably want to pick the most recent one.

Comment: But there aren't going to be 3 appointment records per patient because `LastVisitDate` and `NextApptDate` are distinct. I have had no issues in the past with duplicate rows and have been joining the Demographics and Appointment tables this way all along. The duplicates started when I added the new `CASE` statement today because the inactive indicator is for some reason creating a new distinct record instead of just being added to the existing record.

Comment: As others have told you. Nothing in the SELECT clause will ever add duplicate rows. Tell me this, does this return anything? `SELECT PatientID, COUNT(*) FROM Appointment GROUP BY PatientID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Answer (score 0):

Consider joining to an aggregated *Appointment* resultset that returns last visit date and next appointment date per `PatientID`. Then, you can join for a or 1:1 comparison.

```sql
WITH appt_agg (
   SELECT PatientID
         , MAX(LastVisitDate) AS LastVisitDate
         , MIN(NextApptDate) AS NextApptDate
   FROM Appointment 
   GROUP BY PatientID
)

SELECT d.PatientID
    , d.PatientName
    , ...[other demographic fields like DOB, gender, race]

    , a.LastVisitDate
    , a.NextApptDate
    , (CASE
          WHEN a.LastVisitDate > DATEADD(yy, -3, GETDATE()) 
          THEN 'YES'
          ELSE NULL
       END) AS [Active?]
    , (CASE
          WHEN d.PatientFlag = 'Inactive Patient!' 
          THEN 'YES'
          ELSE NULL
       END) AS [Inactive Flag?]

FROM Demographic d 
LEFT JOIN appt_gg a
    ON d.PatientID = a.PatientID
```